# Event handling in Windows Store Apps using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store App using the MVVM pattern (no framework, just raw MVVM).

I have a user control `DropboxFileplanUserControl.xaml` which has an associated view model `DropboxFileplanViewModel.cs`. `DropboxFileplanUserControl` is embedded in `MainPage.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml` has an associated view model, `MainPageViewModel.cs`.

My question is **how can I define and raise an event in `DropboxFileplanViewModel.cs` and handle it in `MainPageViewModel.cs`?** Assume the event to be raised is called `ImageLoaded`.

**EDIT:** I have added the following specific code snippets...

**DropboxFileplanUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="PhotoBox.Controls.DropboxFileplanUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PhotoBox.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="using:PhotoBox.ViewModels"
xmlns:triggers="using:WinRT.Triggers"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="200">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:DropboxFileplanViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListBox>
    <!-- 
        ...
        ...
        Here I define a ListBox and use interaction triggers to bind the SelectionChanged event to FileplanSelectionChangedCommand on the ViewModel -->
         <triggers:Interactions.Triggers>
            <triggers:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <triggers:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FileplanSelectionChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </triggers:EventTrigger>
        </triggers:Interactions.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**DropboxFileplanViewModel.xaml** *Note: I've stripped out a lot of code from this snippet*

```
public class DropboxFileplanViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand FileplanSelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public DropboxFileplanViewModel()
    {
        FileplanSelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(FileplanSelectionChanged);
    }

    private void FileplanSelectionChanged(object parameter)
    {
        var args = (SelectionChangedEventArgs) parameter;

        // Some other stuff is done here but ultimately,
        // GetImageFile is called

    }

    private async void GetImageFile(MetaData file)
    {
        // Stuff is done here to get the image

        // ******************************                        
        // Here I want to raise the event
        // ******************************    
    }
}
```

`DropboxFileplanUserControl` is embedded in `MainPage.xaml` as follows...

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<controls:DropboxFileplanUserControl
            Grid.Row="0"
            DataContext="{Binding FileplanControl}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsOpen}"
            <!-- *** Here I need to access the ImageLoaded event and bind it to a command in MainPageViewModel.cs *** -->
            />
```

So, to summarise, I need to declare and raise an event in `DropboxFileplanViewModel.cs` and access this event in `MainPage.xaml` so I can then handle it in `MainPageViewModel.cs`. I know how to bind the event in `MainPage.xaml` to a command in `MainPageViewModel`, I just need to know how to do the first bit, i.e. declaring and raising an event in `DropboxFileplanViewModel.cs` and accessing it in `MainPage.xaml`.

Comment: Are you using a base class to store your viewmodels like ViewModelLocator (mvvm light)? Can you put some code up for your xaml and viewmodels?

Comment: The inheritance hierarchy of my viewmodels is `ViewModel : BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged`. I tried to keep my original question as generic as possible with regards to class names but I will edit the post with actual code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the code. An easy way to do this is using the Messenger class in mvvmlight but thought I'd check first before putting an answer up as you're not using a framework.

Answer (score 3):

In XAML:

```
<Image Loaded="ImageLoaded" ... />
```

In xaml.cs:

```
public MainPageViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
    }
}

public void ImageLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
    // call down to your view model
    if( ViewModel != null )
    {
        ViewModel.ImageLoadedHandler( );
    }
}
```

In response to your comment, the idea is the same for the custom `UserControl`. I have (what I think is) and interesting solution I don't often see others implement. It's the idea that each ViewModel has an associated View (I call it owner) and a logical parent. Similar to the visual tree XAML/WinRT constructs that allows for traversal of UI elements, the parent/owner relationship we can create in our ViewModels allow this same style of traversal in our back-end code. Consider the following:

Assume we have a custom `UserControl` called `MyUserControl` that resides in the namespace `MyProject`.

In MainPageView.xaml:

```
<Page xmlns:local="MyProject"> // or whatever your fancy-pants namespace scheme is
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding InnerVM}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In you MainPageView.xaml.cs

```
public MainPageViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
    }
}

public MainPageView()
{
    InitializeComponent( );

    DataContext = new MainPageViewModel( null, this );
}
```

We're getting there. Now let's look at MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase // I'll explain ViewModelBase momentarily
{
    public MyUserControlViewModel InnerVM { get; set; } // should be a notifying property

    public MainPageViewModel( ViewModelBase parent, FrameworkElement owner )
        : base( parent, owner )
    {
    }
}
```

For all intents and purposes, MyUserControlViewModel.cs is the same.

Here is ViewModelBase.cs (with some abridgments):

```
public ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase Parent { get; set; } // should be a notifying property
    public FrameworkElement Owner { get; set; } // should be a notifying property

    public ViewModelBase( ViewModelBase parent, FrameworkElement owner )
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Simple! Right? Now what does that actually do for us? Let's see. Consider the following:

In MyUserControl.xaml:

```
<Image Loaded="ImageLoaded" ... />
```

In MyUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public MyUserControlVieWModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataContext as MyUserControlVieWModel;
    }
}

public void ImageLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
    // call down to your view model
    if( ViewModel != null )
    {
        ViewModel.ImageLoadedHandler( );
    }
}
```

MyUserControlViewModel.cs

Now you have two options here (and I just realized I may be over-explaining the issue for you, and I apologize. Please heavily consider option 1 for your question):

1- Use Events!

```
public event EventHandler ImageLoaded = delegate { };

public void OnImageLoaded( )
{
    ImageLoaded( );
}
```

Then in MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public void OnImageLoaded( )
{
    // handle the image loading
}
```

And now maybe put this in your constructor:

```
...
InnerVM.ImageLoaded += OnImageLoaded;
...
```

Now when the event is fired from within MyUserControl, MainPageViewModel will be able to respond.

The second option requires more explination, and I have to run for now. But hopefully this gets you going. Sorry for the short ending. Please respond with questions if you need to. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks William, that gives me the code for handling the event in `MainPageViewModel.cs`. Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question but I need to raise the event from a user control's view model, `MyUserControlViewModel.cs`. The user control itself `MyUserControl.xaml` is embedded in `MainPage.xaml`. Could you provide a code snippet showing how this would be achieved?